# Docker-compose Nuxtjs

Tags: docker-compose, nuxtjs

I am creating my first Nuxtjs app but I want to use Docker-compose. I was able to Dockerize my application following this tutorial: https://dockerize.io/guides/docker-nuxtjs-guide

Now I want to bring it to the next level using compose but I'm not too familiar with Serverside-rendering and how this could affect my docker-compose file. Unfortunately I cannot find any guide on how to use docker-compose on NuxtJS apps. Do you know where I can find a good guide for it? Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
I created a docker-compose.yml file and is working but still I can't find any guide to see if it is a good yml file (best practices etc.)

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: npm run dev
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you can already run your app in Docker, you won't gain much from Docker Compose, unless you need to run multiple containers. As stated in [Overview of Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/), Compose is a tool for defining and running **multi-container** Docker applications.

Based on the linked tutorial, `docker-compose.yaml` could look something like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
  nuxt:
    image: nuxtjs-tutorial:latest
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      - NUXT_HOST="0.0.0.0"
      - NUXT_PORT="3000"
```

The environment variables do not need to be set from the Compose file, this is just an example. Compose allows you to set many options, as described in the [Compose file reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/). For example, you could run the app in Compose using [`entrypoint`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#entrypoint) instead of `CMD` in `Dockerfile`. Or you could only copy `package.json` in `Dockerfile`, build the dependencies during image build, and mount your code using [`volumes`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes).

I found multiple example references online, but I wouln't consider any of them best practice. Best to read the official Documentation.

Regarding your update, based on the `Dockerfile` in the tutorial, you do not even need the `build` and `command` entries, only `image` and `ports`. But as I said above, you can set many options from Compose, best described in official documentation.

Comment: Thank you @touchmarine, the only thing is the port shouldn't be in quotes: `NUXT_PORT=3000` . same for the NUXT_HOST.

Comment: Ehi there is a problem with this: when I modify the app on my local, the changes do not reflects on my running container!

Comment: When you change your app, you need to build the image again and rerun the container/compose. To mitigate this, you can create a `docker-compose.dev.yaml` with a volume mount as I briefly mentioned in the anwser. First, in `Dockerfile`, instead of copying everything from your cwd, copy only the dependency list files, like `package.json` and `package-lock.json`. You can do this by changing `COPY` in `Dockerfile` or add other files to `.dockerignore`. Then rebuild the image. In `docker-compose.dev.yaml` add something like
`volumes:
  - .:/usr/src/nuxt/app`.

Comment: After that, you need to also set an `entrypoint` in the compose file that will run NuxtJS watch process. The volume mount defined in the previous comment, will make the container use the files from your host, instead of the files copied during the build process. I hope this comments help you atleast a bit. Oh, and when running this, make sure to use the proper docker-compose file, like so: `docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yaml up`.